# Elasticsearch Nested-field vs Depth? Check for document depth via Kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm reading about mapping in [elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html#mapping-limit-settings) and I see these 2 terms: Nested-field & Depth. I think these 2 terms are quite equivalent. I'm currently confused by these 2. Please can anyone clear me out? Thank you.
And btw, are there any ways to check a document depth via Kibana?

Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The source of confusion is probably because in Elasticsearch term `nested` can be used in two different contexts:

- "nested" as a regular [JSON notation nested](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_objects.asp), i.e. JSON object within JSON object;
- "nested" as Elasticsearch [`nested` data type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/nested.html).

In the [mappings documentation page](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/mapping.html#mapping-limit-settings) when they mention "depth" they refer to the first meaning. Here the setting `index.mapping.depth.limit` defines how deeply nested can your JSON documents be.

#### How is JSON depth interpreted by Elasticsearch mapping?

Here is an example of JSON document with depth 1:

```
 {
    "name": "John",
    "age": 30
 }
```

Now with depth 2:

```
 {
    "name": "John",
    "age": 30,
    "cars": {
        "car1": "Ford",
        "car2": "BMW",
        "car3": "Fiat"
    }
 }
```

By default (as of ES 6.3) the depth [cannot exceed 20](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/mapping.html#mapping-limit-settings).

#### What is a `nested` data type and why isn't it the same as a document with depth>1?

[`nested`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/nested.html) data type allows to index arrays of objects and query their items individually via [`nested` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/query-dsl-nested-query.html). What this means is that Elasticsearch will index a document with such fields differently (see the page [Nested Objects](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-objects.html) of the Definitive Guide for more explanation).

For instance, if in the following example we do not define `"user"` as `nested` field in the mapping, a query for `user.first: John` and `user.last: White` will return a match and it will be a mistake:

```
{
  "group" : "fans",
  "user" : [ 
    {
      "first" : "John",
      "last" :  "Smith"
    },
    {
      "first" : "Alice",
      "last" :  "White"
    }
  ]
}
```

If we do, Elasticsearch will index each item of the `"user"` list as an implicit sub-document and thus will use more resources, more disk and memory. This is why there is also another setting on the mappings: [`index.mapping.nested_fields.limit`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/mapping.html) regulates how many different `nested` fields one can declare (which defaults to `50`). To customize this you can see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59484227/limiting-the-nested-fields-in-elasticsearch).

So, Elasticsearch documents with depth > 1 are not indexed as `nested` unless you explicitly ask it to do so, and that's the difference.

#### Can I have `nested` fields inside `nested`?

Yes, you can! Just to stop this confusion, yes, you can define a `nested` field inside `nested` field in a mapping. It will look something like this:

```
PUT my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "user": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "name": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "cars": {
              "type": "nested",
              "properties": {
                "brand": {
                  "type": "keyword"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But keep in mind that the amount of implicit documents to be indexed will be multiplied, and it will be simply not that efficient.

#### Can I get the depth of my JSON objects from Kibana?

Most likely you can do it with scripts, check this blog post for further details: [Using Painless in Kibana scripted fields](https://www.elastic.co/blog/using-painless-kibana-scripted-fields).

Comment: Thanks, this helped me to understand better, ES docs are horrible.
I did had to dig in the web how to change the setting, here is where I found to free you a few searches: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59484227/limiting-the-nested-fields-in-elasticsearch