# Elastic-search query to list lowest price products first

Tags: elasticsearch

In my elastic-search indexed eCommerce application, One product has multiple suppliers and each supplier may have their own original price and discount price etc.

If the user searches for the product i need to show lowest price supplier details(in search result page as well as product detail page). 
How can i prepare the elasticsearch multimatch query to fetch relevant records with price/offerPrice in ascending order?
Is there any better design than this?

I have created the index in Elastic search in following nested object format

```
{
   "skuId": "100",
   "skuName": "I-Phone",
   "Sellers": {
      "seller": [
         {
            "Supplier": {
               "SupplierId": 1,
               "supplierAlias": "X1",
               "supplierDesc": "X1"
            },
            "price": 10,
            "offerPrice": 8
         },
         {
            "Supplier": {
               "SupplierId": 2,
               "supplierAlias": "X2",
               "supplierDesc": "X2"
            },
            "price": 9,
            "offerPrice": null
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: In Elasticsearch `nested` has peculiar meaning, please check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51455007/5095957) that explains it. Using [`nested`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html) data type will help, but it is not the only option available.

Answer (score 0):

if you need order seller array in you index, you have two solution
1st you can use any programming language to order this array after find your target document.
2nd you can re-index the data with separate documents to make full control on it.